# Как узнать, сколько памяти занимают различные объекты в Unity билде?

Tags: unity3d, память

Есть собранный билд под андройд, занимающий 50мб. После сборки я захожу в open log, чтобы посмотреть статистику занимаемой разными объектами памяти, но вижу там только количество оперативно памяти.
Можно ли где-нибудь найти похожую статистику (объект - память) только не оперативной, а физической памяти (т.е. в процентах от 50мб)?
Я новичок в разработке, поэтому буду рад любым советам. Спасибо :)

Answer (score 0):

Если под объектом вы имеете в виду скрипт и сколько он занимает то:

- Unity Profiler в помощь. Window > Analytics > Profiler

Если вам нужно узнать сколько занимает памяти объект как GameObject то рекомендую почитать вот эти статьи:

- [https://answers.unity.com/questions/1470153/whay-is-the-size-of-monobehaviour-instance.html#:~:text=The%20minimum%20size%20is%20actually,(even%20an%20empty%20class)](https://answers.unity.com/questions/1470153/whay-is-the-size-of-monobehaviour-instance.html#:%7E:text=The%20minimum%20size%20is%20actually,(even%20an%20empty%20class)).
- https://answers.unity.com/questions/36059/is-there-a-way-to-know-the-system-memory-used-by-a.html

В этих статьсях задача решалась в лоб. т.е. объект > на нем скрипт(20б) + текстура(2мб) = общее(2мб 20б)

Answer (score 0):

Рекомендую использовать Analyze APK file в Android Studio, как по мне очень практичный инструмент для анализа